# React Hook Form not validating nested input field until I call onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, onchange, react-hook-form

I have a form which has 2 fields.

1. Heading
2. Dynamic List which contains Name & Image

I'm able to validate changes whenever Heading or Name inside dynamic list is changed.

But when I change Image, the validation is failing. It returns true instead of showing error message. I tried adding a text input to test the image. Whenever I call onChange it is working fine.

Here is my code:

```
  

import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import * as z from "zod";


const schema = z.object({
  heading: z
    .string()
    .min(3, { message: "Min 3 characters" })
    .max(40, { message: "Max 40 characters" }),
  testimonials: z.array(
    z.object({
      name: z.string().min(3, { message: "Min 3 characters" }),
      image: z.string().url({ message: "Invalid URL" }),
    })
  ),
});

const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
  formState: { errors },
} = useForm({
  resolver: zodResolver(schema),
});

const [dataObj, setDataObj] = useState({
    "heading": "",
    "testimonials": []
});


const fetchData = () => {
  
    // fetch list from server 
    // bind data 
    setDataObj(dataFromServer);
};

fetchData();

const listChanged = (type, value, index) => {
  let list = dataObj.data.testimonials;

  if (type == "name") {
    list[index].name = value;
  } else if (type == "image") {
    list[index].image = value;
  }

  setDataObj({
    ...dataObj,
    testimonials: list,
  });
};


const headingChanged = (value) => {

  setDataObj({
    ...dataObj,
    heading: value,
  });
};
 


<form className="mt-10 space-y-6" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <div
    className={`relative appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2 border rounded-md shadow-sm placeholder-gray-400  sm:text-sm ${
      errors.heading
        ? "border-red-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500"
        : "border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500"
    }`}
  >
    <label
      htmlFor="name"
      className="absolute -top-2 left-2 -mt-px inline-block bg-white px-1 text-xs font-medium text-gray-400"
    >
      Section Heading
    </label>
    <div className="mt-1">
      <input
        type="text"
        autoComplete="name"
        {...register("heading", {
          required: true,
        })}
        className="block w-full border-0 p-0 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm"
        value={dataObj.data.title}
        onChange={(e) => headingChanged( e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
    {errors.heading && (
      <small className="mt-2 text-xs text-red-500">
        {errors.heading.message}
      </small>
    )}
  </div>

  <div className="mt-2 w-full py-2">
    <div>
      <div className="mt-2 flex justify-center mx-auto text-left">
        <ul role="list" className="w-full">
          {dataObj.data.testimonials.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={index} className="py-3">
              <div className="flex items-center space-x-4 justify-start w-full">
                <div className="isolate -space-y-px rounded-md shadow-sm w-full">
                  <div
                    className={`appearance-none relative w-full px-3 py-2 border rounded-md rounded-b-none shadow-sm sm:text-sm ${
                      errors.testimonials?.[index]?.name
                        ? "border-red-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500"
                        : "border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500"
                    }`}
                  >
                    <label
                      htmlFor="name"
                      className="absolute -top-2 left-2 -mt-px inline-block bg-white px-1 text-xs font-medium text-gray-400"
                    >
                      Name
                    </label>
                    <input
                      {...register(`testimonials.${index}.name`)}
                      type="text"
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        listChanged(index, e.target.value, "name");
                      }}
                      value={item.name}
                      placeholder="New Label"
                      className="block w-full border-0 p-1.5 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm"
                    />
                    <span className="invalid-feedback text-red-500 text-xs">
                      {errors.testimonials?.[index]?.name?.message}
                    </span>
                  </div>

                  <div className="relative rounded-md rounded-t-none border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 focus-within:ring-0 focus-within:ring-indigo-600">
                    <label
                      htmlFor="name"
                      className="absolute -top-2 left-2 -mt-px inline-block bg-white px-1 text-xs font-medium text-gray-400"
                    >
                      Image
                    </label>
                    <input
                      {...register(`testimonials.${index}.image`)}
                      type="text"
                      value={item.image}
                    />
                    <UploadImage
                      size={`small-round`}
                      index={index}
                      imageUrl={item.image}
                      imageChanged={listChanged}
                    />
                    <span className="invalid-feedback text-red-500 text-xs">
                      {errors.testimonials?.[index]?.image?.message}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>;
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Is the `UploadImage` component registered with RHF? If it's a custom component, you might need to change `imageChanged` function to call RHF's `onChange` with updated value.

Comment: can you provide codesandbox url.

Answer (score 1):

I have created following minimum example on how to use `image` with `useFieldArray` to create dynamic form. This has been created in codesandbox and tested for validation only. Let me know if you stuck anywhere or want more information.

SandBoxLink : [image: Edit prod-browser-w7bxwm]

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm, useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import * as z from "zod";

const MAX_FILE_SIZE = 200000;
const ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES = ["image/jpeg", "image/png"];

const schema = z.object({
  heading: z
    .string()
    .min(3, { message: "Min 3 characters" })
    .max(40, { message: "Max 40 characters" }),
  testimonials: z.array(
    z.object({
      name: z.string().min(3, { message: "Min 3 characters" }),
      testimonial: z.string().min(3, { message: "Min 3 characters" }),
      image: z
        .any()
        .refine(
          (files) => files?.[0]?.size <= MAX_FILE_SIZE,
          `Max image size is 2MB.`
        )
        .refine(
          (files) => ACCEPTED_IMAGE_TYPES.includes(files?.[0]?.type),
          "Only .jpg, .png formats are supported."
        )
    })
  )
});

const App = () => {
  const appendValues = {
    Name: "",
    testimonial: "",
    image: []
  };

  const defaultValues = {
    heading: "",
    testimonials: [appendValues]
  };

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues,
    resolver: zodResolver(schema)
  });
  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "testimonials"
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label htmlFor="heading">Heading : </label>
      <input {...register("heading")} id="heading" />
      <p>{errors?.heading?.message}</p>
      {fields.map((field, index) => (
        <div
          key={field.id}
          style={{
            border: "1px solid black",
            padding: "10px"
          }}
        >
          <label htmlFor={`testimonials.${index}.name`}>Name : </label>
          <input
            id={`test.${index}.name`}
            {...register(`testimonials.${index}.name`)}
          />
          <p>{errors.testimonials?.[index]?.name?.message}</p>
          <br />
          <label htmlFor={`testimonials.${index}.testimonial`}>
            Testimonial :
          </label>
          <input
            id={`test.${index}.testimonial`}
            {...register(`testimonials.${index}.testimonial`)}
          />
          <p>{errors.testimonials?.[index]?.testimonial?.message}</p>
          <br />
          <label htmlFor={`testimonials.${index}.image`}>Image :</label>
          <input
            id={`test.${index}.image`}
            type="file"
            {...register(`testimonials.${index}.image`)}
          />
          <p>{errors.testimonials?.[index]?.image?.message}</p>
          <br />
          <button type="button" onClick={() => remove(index)}>
            Remove
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
      <button type="button" onClick={() => append(appendValues)}>
        append
      </button>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Could you share the codesandbox link

Comment: I have added codesandbox link in answer